# Cannot get all the rows from Datastax Astra DB

Tags: datastax-astra

I am not getting all the rows from my Datastax Astra DB where I have uploaded my data. I am using python `http_methods` for requesting data. Here is my code-

```
respond = astra_client.request(
        method=http_methods.GET,
        path=f"/api/rest/v2/keyspaces/{ASTRA_DB_KEYSPACE}/{astra_db_collection}/rows")
```

This method is only getting me 100 rows, while there are 150 rows in my table. How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

The default page size for this endpoint is 100. To return more rows you'll want to set the query param `.../rows?page-size=N`.

If your page size is smaller than the total dataset you would like to return you'll need to use paging. This can be accomplished with `page-size=N&page-state=SOME_PAGE_STATE` where `SOME_PAGE_STATE` is the string returned in the `pageState` field of the response body.